# Is following subset W of V also a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Under following conditions

$ a, b \in \mathbb{R}, V = \mathbb{R}^{2}, W = \{(x, y)\ |\ ax + by = 0 \} $

is W a subspace of V? I know the basics, but how would I prove that addition and multiplication are closed over this subset?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $(v_1,v_2),(w_1,w_2)\in W.$ We have 
$$\begin{cases} 
av_1+bv_2=0\\
aw_1+bw_2=0
\end{cases}
$$
What happens when you add these equations? What happens when you multiply the first equation by a real number $r$?

Comment: Thanks, this is actually very clear to me now.. I feel stupid for not seeing that myself. So it is obviously a subspace, since both new equations you mention are still zero?

Comment: Comment corrected. Yes. Only you need to use the algebraic properties of the real numbers to see the vectors $(v_1+w_1,v_2+w_2)$ and $(rv_1,rv_2)$ in the resulting equations.

Comment: Yes, of course. Thanks a lot!